# automatic rota system based on special conditions

Tags: excel

I am trying to create system for assigning tasks to a team using existing sequence. I have four separate columns:

```
Column A – Indicates the given sequence of operators
Column B – Indicates number of current tasks per operator (imported from another file by vlookup)
Column C – Indicates the name of the operator that was assigned to the last task (imported from another file by vlookup)
Column D – Indicates whether any of the operators are currently on holiday (check/uncheck check box (TRUE/FALSE logic)
```

I would like to automate the system so that the next operator that is due to receive tasks is displayed, however the operator must not have more than 4 tasks already assigned to him/her and must be present (not on holiday).

The selection process must repeat taking into consolidation the given sequence until the name is selected, hence if the last name in the sequence is not the exact match the system must start with the first name in the sequence.

Could someone be able to figure this out please as I am completely stock.
Currently, I have the following, column with the following `=IF(B2<=4,A2,"N/A")` and another column with the following `=IF(E2=FALSE,F2,"N/A")`. And one more column with `=INDEX(SQESequence,MATCH(C2,SQESequence,0)+1,1)`, however that  is not fully automated.

Comment: Hi Kalamarico, would you be able to help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that I understand your problem / question and have come up with a solution. A more elegant formula solution may exist, will play with it more if I have time.

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(C2,A2:A5)+1&":A5"),MATCH(1,(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(C2,A2:A5)+1&":A5")<>$C$2)*(INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(C2,A2:A5)+1&":B5")<4)*(INDIRECT("D"&MATCH(C2,A2:A5)+1&":D5")=FALSE),0)),INDEX($A$2:$A$5,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$5<>$C$2)*($B$2:$B$5<4)*($D$2:$D$5=FALSE),0)))}
```

Enter CTRL SHIFT ENTER to set as an array formula, each function then returns an array of values rather than just a single value. You know you have set as an array formula when you see the { } 's

They say that a picture is worth 1000 words....so here are three!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help with this. I was trying to apply it but it seems that the given sequence is not followed by the formula when looking for the next available person who has less than 4 tasks already assigned to them. Please see below where the last person assigned the task is "B" which means that the next person should be "D", however for some reason the formula is picking person "A"? I apologise for this but could you help again please.

Comment: *facepalm* I missed the heart of the problem LOL. Happens. Latest edit should have it. Let me know!

Comment: Hi There, could you tell me how to paste images into the comment box please I cannot figure it out so that I can show you what exactly is happening.

Comment: Hi, I would like to add an image of the excel sheet exactly the same way you have added the images of the sheet above. How is that done? Anyway, the issue I have observed with the formula is that when all the operators listed in the sequence have the same amount of tasks assigned to them, 3 tasks in this case, some operators are skipped. So instead of operator B being selected after operator A, it goes to operator D.

Comment: I am not getting this issue, it properly rotates to the next available operator. Are you sure that all of the vacation "properties" are set to false?

Comment: yes, all the items in the vacation column are set to false and yet row 2 and 3 gets skipped. To be perfectly honest, I could not even offer any possible solutions as the formula you gave me is way beyond my excel skills.

Comment: I added two more photos that should show that it does not skip even if the # tasks are equal. there may be more elegant/simpler solutions but I have not come up with one, don't have time to find! sorry.

Comment: in the header of your editing interface there is an icon, looks like a frame with outline of mountain in it. it is for inserting images. so under OP click edit, look for that icon, then follow instructions. curious as to if its working or not LOL

Comment: Still not working but thank you for the help, could you do me one favour though, could you explain how the formula works as I would like to understand the formula

Comment: Not sure how it is not working tbh. Regardles.....We are using the indirect match statements to shrink the range that we are searching through to only those which come after our last task. If our last task was the last "sequence" then the entire range is used. We use match(1, Conditions) to get a match for the first set of conditions whose value is true. The row that the Match(1,Conditions) returns is used by the index to get a value.